# execCommand('insertHTML') is eating up the space

Tags: javascript

In the below code I am highlight a selected text by using `execCommand('insertHTML')`

**Problem:**

When I select first *selectme* below. It eats up the space between *selectme* and *Test*. But the same problem doesnt occur when I select second *selectme*

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event)=>{
 const selection = window.getSelection().toString();
 document.execCommand('insertHTML', false,
      `<span class="bg-red">${selection}</span>`);
});
```

```css
.bg-red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
      selectme <span class="bg-red">TEST</span> 
      selectme <span class="bg-red">TEST</span>
</div>
```

**Browser:**

*Google Chrome
Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

5 sec GIF below

[image]

Comment: functionality is working fine & there is no any error in the code.

Comment: Seems like its a chorme spacific issue. Can you try in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I did this with another way

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener('mouseup', (event)=>{
            var select = window.getSelection();

            //store selected text
            var sel_txt = select.toString();

            if(sel_txt){    

                  //get ranges currently selected
                  var range = select.getRangeAt(0);
                  
                  //remove range content from the document
                  range.deleteContents();

                  //create node for replace
                  var elm = document.createElement('span');
                  elm.className = "bg-red";
                  var textNode = document.createTextNode(sel_txt);
                  elm.appendChild(textNode);
                  
                  //insert node
                  range.insertNode(elm);

                  //remove selection
                  select.removeAllRanges();
            }
    });
```

```css
.bg-red{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
      selectme <span class="bg-red">TEST</span> 
      selectme <span class="bg-red">TEST</span>
</div>
```